# Can Gauss's law be generalized to use with other massless vector fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, field-theory, gauss-law

Can we use the integral form of Gauss's law for other types of massless vector fields?  For example, if I'm thinking of the graviton field, is there any reason why it would not apply? (understanding that the graviton field is not proven yet).  If I'm way off base with this, is there another function that would be better suited?

Comment: It works for gravity

Comment: @Ben51 Can you expand on that or give me a reference?

Comment: The graviton field (classically, just gravity, which has certainly been confirmed to exist and propagate) is not a vector field but a tensor.

Comment: It’s not profound. Gauss law works because the field due to a point source goes like $r^{-2}$ and the surface area of a sphere around the point goes like $r^2$. Combine those with superposition and you have the law.

Comment: @foolishmuse Ben is talking about the Newtonian gravitational field. Buzz is talking about General Relativity.

Comment: Gauss's law would be mainly Newtonian I guess.

Comment: Gauss's Law doesn't hold in GR, but it does hold in the Newtonian limit $c\rightarrow\infty$ of GR and it does hold in Newtonian gravity, since the potential in Newtonian gravity obeys the Poisson equation just like the scalar potential in electromagnetism. (And for a point charge in electromagnetism / point mass in the Newtonian limit of GR, the electric field / local gravitational acceleration is just the gradient of the potential; there is no curl).

Comment: @Andrew  One of the first reasons I looked at this for gravity was because of curl.  Wouldn't the curl equate to frame dragging, particularly the substantial frame dragging around a black hole.

Comment: It's related. There is a subject called gravitoelectromagnetism which tries to exploit an analogy between the equations of GR and electromagnetism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism The "magnetic" part of the gravitational field is indeed related to frame dragging. However, the analogy isn't perfect, and the purist in me prefers the explanation of frame dragging in full GR in terms of a metric, not a "gravitomagnetic field."